# How do you set a document parameter in a LotusScript function?

Tags: lotusscript

Consider example below. preferencesDoc is passed in as nothing. Its assignment in this function is ignored and it remains nothing after the set. tmpDoc is set fine. Both assignments are identical, so it's not a view issue. The assignment of preferencesDoc is blocked, apparently because it's a parameter. There are no errors and the by-key lookup works fine, which is proven by successful assignment of tmpDoc.

```
Function test(preferencesDoc As NotesDocument) 
    If preferencesDoc Is Nothing then
        Set preferencesDoc=docLookupView.getDocumentByKey("GENERAL_PREFERENCES", True)
    End if

    Dim tmpDoc As NotesDocument
    Set tmpDoc=docLookupView.getDocumentByKey("GENERAL_PREFERENCES", True)
End Function
```

Can someone explain what's going on here and how to go about it?

**Clarification.**

It's great to see people chipping in ideas. However, you must realize this function here is just to illustrate my problem. It's a bare-bones method that helps me communicate the issue and is not part of my real code. Please stay on the question.

Again, if preferencesDoc is passed in as nothing, its "fix" assignment in the function is utterly ignored. Tode seems to be onto something. When I pass in preferenceDoc that is set, I can reassign it to a different doc.

**Answer**

```
call test(Nothing) // will not work

---

Dim doc as NotesDocument
call test(doc) // will work
```

Key statement from Tode: If you pass "Nothing" as Parameter, then it will stay nothing. If you pass an uninitialized NotesDocument, then it will be initialized.

Both Tode and Knut hit the point and I think Rich is hinting at the same thing. Thanks. I believe Knut was first, so I'll give credit to him.

All the years that I have been coding in Notes, and this is the first time I'm running into this issue. Learning something every day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work. Just call your function with `Call test(doc)` You can test it with

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Call test(doc)
If doc Is Nothing Then
    Print "Nothing"
Else
    Print doc.form(0)
End If
```

A more comfortable way to get the preference document is using no parameter:

```
Function GeneralPreferences() As NotesDocument
    Static preferencesDoc As NotesDocument
    If preferencesDoc Is Nothing Then
        ' ... get your docLookupView
        Set preferencesDoc=docLookupView.getDocumentByKey("GENERAL_PREFERENCES", True)
    End If
    Set GeneralPreferences = preferencesDoc
End Function
```

Then you can work with the result like this

```
Print GeneralPreferences.form(0)
Print GeneralPreferences.created
```

and you don't need to have an extra NotesDocument declared. With the preferencesDoc's `Static` the document is only read one time from database - it is "cached" in the function

Comment: Yes, but as soon as you pass in "nothing" you can not assign any other value to that variable anymore, it will stay "nothing"...

Comment: I understood that the passed parameter is a NotesDocument which is not set yet and that's why "Nothing" like in my example

Comment: Knut, thanks. General Preferences is a single document and this would be an alternative but I have other doc parameters in my real function signature, so I really need to figure out what's going on with the parameters.

Comment: @jacekn, did you try the test above? You have to place a NotesDocument as parameter. It will be used as target variable for the document.

Comment: You can't call "test(Nothing)". You have to give a NotesDocument variable as parameter "test(doc)". Before the call you have to define "doc" as NotesDocument. Like in my test example above.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal in LotusScript. If you pass in "nothing", then this is NOT an Object of type NotesDocument but simply "Nothing"... And Nothing can not be assigned a value.

But you already did the right thing: use a function.

You call the function like this:

```
Set preferenceDoc = test(preferenceDoc)
```

is correct. But you forget to deliver back a document. Your function should look like this:

```
Function test(preferenceDoc as NotesDocument) As NotesDocument
  Dim docTemp as NoresDocument
  If preferenceDoc is Nothing then
    Set docTemp = docLkpView.GetDocumentBykey( "GENERAL_PREFERENCES", True )
  Else
    Set docTemp = preferenceDoc
  End If
  ' here comes the "magic"
  Set test=docTemp
End Function
```

Of course you could take out docTemp completely and just replace docTemp by the function name in the corresponding lines, then you don't need the last line...

Comment: Hi Tode, question is about parameter assignment and function only illustrate my problem. Let's not discuss this function and stay on the question.

Comment: If you pass "Nothing" as Parameter, then it will stay nothing. If you pass an uninitialized NotesDocument, then it will be initialized. If this does not work for you, then most probably the context gets lost... If you e.g. Define a database in your sub test and create the "Nothing"- doc in that database, then it will be empty as soon as you leave the sub, as the parent object is Nothing... I assume, that the problem is in your "Real" code, as the example you gave would work (if you pass a variable of type NotesDocument)

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference, so the behavior you are describing definitely seems odd. But as a matter of style I would not recommend doing that anyhow. Sode-effects obscure the logic of your code.  Your function should be declared to return a NotesDocument, and should be invoked via

```
Set doc = test(doc)
```

Comment: Hi Rich, this function does not need to return notesDocument. This is just a quick example to illustrate my problem with the parameter re-assignment.

Comment: It seems the quick example is not getting your point across.  Are you having this problem with multiple parameters passed to a single sub or function?  They should be passed by reference, so assigned values should "stick" -- unless you have a containment scope problem (i.e., the parent of the object goes out of scope prior to the function or sub returning), or unless there's nothing to stick to (because you passed Nothing in the call to the function or sub).

Comment: If I read the question right, the function is called as "Call test(Nothing)" or plain "test Nothing". The temporary variable preferencesDoc is then set to Nothing, the function code executes and sets preferencesDoc to a valid NotesDocument, but at the end of the function the values is to be placed back by reference. Since the parameter to the function was a constant or expression and not a variable that could be referenced, no value is returned. By the way, where would you have expected that value??